# CSS VScrollbar lag

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, lag

Try to apply box-shadow to thumb on scrollbar.
Scrollbar on div element.

When scrolling box-shadow lags
Why? And how to fix it?

[Normal shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHqxN.png)

[Shadow hit the wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es1ni.png)

[Thumb on the wall, shadow normal again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eek22.png)

Looks like box-shadow hits invincible wall or smth like that

And number of walls depends on element height, more height more walls
(Interesting that horisontal scrollbar works right)

Code

```
 <div style="
overflow-Y: scroll; 
overflow-X: hidden; 
width:80vw; 
height:60vh; 
border:3px solid black; 
left:10vw; 
top:10vh;
">
  <div style="
  height: 1400vh; 
  width: 1000vw;
  background:blue; 
  ">
    
  </div>
</div>

    <style>
  div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track  {
   background: red;
 }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: goldenrod;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 10px green;
  }
  </style>
```

Comment: looks like css issue. Please change box shadow to this : `-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px green;`

Comment: Well, thats not solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem solved, for now.
Thats some css lag.
That appears on positioning element.
Static, absolute, relative - has lag
Position fixed - lag disappears.

Mb there are some another solutions

Comment: Also margin set breaks shadow. Even margin 0